# remapping joint states from simulator

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way of remapping the joint states published from Gazebo? I've tried via launch file when launching the gazebo and robot state publisher node.

Usually when I want to do this I remap using the joint state publisher, but since I'm running Gazebo, I do not need the joint state publisher.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/488/remapping-joint-states-from-simulator/) by [seth_g](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/117/seth_g/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-12-12**:
Do you want a mechanism to remap gazebo topics, in a similar manner to ROS? If that is correct, could you please file a feature request on our bitbucket site?

**Comment by [seth_g](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/117/seth_g/) on 2012-12-12**:
Yes, that would solve what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll file a feature this afternoon, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This has been posted on the gazebo issue tracker as [issue 301](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/301).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-25**:
On hold till August ...